# not able to draw image on canvas of surface view in Android

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, drawbitmap

I am drawing an image using drawbitmap method on a canvas of surface view which is an overlay surface on my camera preview.The image drawn is a portion of captured image to guide the user to capture next image with a proper overlap.Now when I am launching the activity as the application start activity i.e it is my first activity,it works fine and draws the image.But when I launch the same activity from some other activity or when i moves back from some other activity,the surface view is not showing image on image capture i.e drawbitmap do not renders the image.
Is there any difference between launching an activity from another activity and from the application launch.

Someone help here as i am not able to proceed...please its important

Comment: need help here please..

Comment: seriously i want some help!
Tried everything..nothing is working
It is strange